# Can't get data just saved in database in Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel-5.1

I successfully save data in the database. However, the data can't be found after saving.

In the JSON，the key object's value is an empty array.

My database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bigdata_db`.`objects` (
  `object_id` CHAR(34) NOT NULL,
  `object_lt_x` FLOAT NOT NULL,
  `object_lt_y` FLOAT NOT NULL,
  `object_width` FLOAT NOT NULL,
  `object_height` FLOAT NOT NULL,
  `image_id` CHAR(34) NOT NULL,
  `type_id` CHAR(34) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`object_id`),
  INDEX `fk_objects_images1_idx` (`image_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_objects_types1_idx` (`type_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_objects_images1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`image_id`)
    REFERENCES `bigdata_db`.`images` (`image_id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_objects_types1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`type_id`)
    REFERENCES `bigdata_db`.`types` (`type_id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

My object model:

```
protected $table = 'objects';
public $timestamps = false;
protected $primaryKey = 'object_id';
public $incrementing = false;
protected $fillable = ['object_id','object_lt_x', 'object_lt_y', 'object_width', 'object_height', 'image_id', 'type_id'];
```

Save the data to database

```
$obj = new Object;
$obj->object_id = $objectId;
$obj->object_lt_x = $objX;
$obj->object_lt_y = $objY;
$obj->object_width = $objWidth;
$obj->object_height = $objHeight;
$obj->image_id = $imageId;
$obj->type_id = $typeId;
if ($obj->save()) {
    $obj_id = $obj->object_id;
    $object = DB::table('objects')->where('object_id',$objectId)->get();
    $success = array('status' => 1,'message' => $type_name.'标记成功！','obj_id' => $obj_id,'object' => $object);
    return response()->json($success);
} else {
    $error = array('status' => 0,'message' => $type_name.'标记失败！');
    return response()->json($error);
}
```

The result is:

```
Object {status: 1, message: "眼睛标记成功！", obj_id: "A7313004-3B7D-56F2-602F-FC81D4A8F04F", object: Array[0]}
```

Comment: show us your database schema

Comment: I add the database schema as you request(I not good at English)

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that you have a conditional for `$obj->save()` but you never actually called `$obj->save();` to save the Entry.

```
$obj = new Object;
$obj->object_id = $objectId;
$obj->object_lt_x = $objX;
$obj->object_lt_y = $objY;
$obj->object_width = $objWidth;
$obj->object_height = $objHeight;
$obj->image_id = $imageId;
$obj->type_id = $typeId;
$obj->save();

if ($obj->save()) {
   $obj_id = $obj->object_id;
   $object = DB::table('objects')->where('object_id',$objectId)->get();
   $success = array('status' => 1,'message' => $type_name.'标记成功！','obj_id' => $obj_id,'object' => $object);
   return response()->json($success);
} else {
    $error = array('status' => 0,'message' => $type_name.'标记失败！');
    return response()->json($error);
```

}

Comment: No, it will be executed in `if ($obj->save())`.